# Returning values in lambda function while using Tkinter button

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-button

I've utilized the lambda function to call two different functions (read_input_data(), which reads data a and b from GUI, and run, which takes the data a and b and makes some computations) after a Tkinter button is pressed

```
start_button = tk.Button(text = 'Start', command = lambda:[ [a,b] = read_input_data(), run(a,b)], bg = 'firebrick', fg = 'white', font = ('helvetica', 9, 'bold'))
```

However, it returns a syntax error. If I remove the outputs [a,b] from read_input_data(), the syntax becomes correct but my code won't work as I need a and b to execute the second function run(a,b).

Comment: Use a normal function instead of `lambda`.

Comment: How did you come up with this `[]` notation?

Comment: Or `lambda: run(*read_input_data())`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lambdas are just a shorthand notation, functionally not much different than an ordinary function defined using `def`, other than allowing only a **single expression**

`x = lambda a, b: a + b`

is really equivalent to

```
def x(a, b):
    return a + b
```

In the same way, what you tried to do would be no different than doing:

```
def x():
    a, b = read_input_data()
    run(a, b)
start_button = tk.Button(text = 'Start', command = x, bg = 'firebrick', fg = 'white', font = ('helvetica', 9, 'bold'))
```

Comment: OP lambda does not have arguments, so your answer is not an answer to OP question.  Also `command=x` expects `x` function does not have arguments.  I wonder why OP accepts this as an answer.

Comment: Maybe because even if it does not work, it shows enough to make adapting the code very straightforward. Also OP's example wasn't really clear in terms of what he is trying to do due to weird use of `[]`.
Anyway I've edited the answer to adress your issues.